# Map values from an UI into QTreeWidget Column

Tags: python, maya, qtreewidget

sorry if my following question sounds stupid but I am pretty much in a lost, big way!

I have created 2 UIs using the Qt-Designer.

- Main UI (anmgToolUI) - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eXVWj99Q
- Sub UI (publishInfoUI) -  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KsnJC8wR

And the following is the main code:
Main Code - http://pastebin.com/mbg2fuvh

And I am using the following to run it in Maya:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/user_data/test')
import UI_test
reload(UI_test)
win = UI_test.MigrationUi()
win.show()
```

So basically what I am trying to achieve here is that the values I have typed in the Sub UI is not mapping the values onto the Main UI.
To replicate the case:

1. Run the execution code
2. Select any of the 2 items that I have already inserted in the Search Filter QTreeWidget and click on "Add Selected" in which it will transfers it into the Migrate ANMG QTreeWidget
3. Select an item in the Migrate ANMG QTreeWidget and click onto the Edit Selected button
4. Try inputting some words etc into either of the 3 fields - Description/ Comment/ Version Comment

I had thought that if I click the `OK` button, it will mapped the values into columns but it does not seems to be that case, despite me setting a signal/slot in the Qt Designer for `accepted()` / `accept()`

Greatly appreciate for any pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented two solutions, you'll need to comment/uncomment the code. The result is the same in both case.

Solution 1 is based on the reference of the asset you are using in `PublishInfoUI` class and. Once you press "OK", the modifcations are done inside the `PublishInfoUI` class on `self.assets`.

On the other side in solution 2, once you press "OK", it creates a new `QTableWidgetItem` which is set then returned to your `MigrationUI` class. Then the modifications are done in this class.

IMO, I prefer the first solution if you rename getValues to updateValues or something like this. But as I said, the result is the same in both case.

```
class MigrationUi(QtGui.QWidget):

    ### Some stuff

    def editSelected(self):
        selected_item = self.ui.treeWidget_migrateAnmg.currentItem()

        if selected_item:
            inputWin = PublishInfoUI(selected_item)
            ############################
            # Here is the core modifications
            if inputWin.exec_(): #Triggered if we press "OK"
                #Solution 1:
                inputWin.getValues()
                #End solution 1

                #Solution 2:
                returnedAsset = inputWin.getValues()
                print "Returned asset: "
                print returnedAsset.text(0)
                print returnedAsset.text(1)
                print returnedAsset.text(2)
                print returnedAsset.text(3)
                print returnedAsset.text(4)
                print returnedAsset.text(5)
                print returnedAsset.text(6)
                print returnedAsset.text(7)
                print returnedAsset.text(8)
                selected_item.setText(6, returnedAsset.text(6) )
                selected_item.setText(7, returnedAsset.text(7) )
                selected_item.setText(8, returnedAsset.text(8) )
                #End solution 2
            else:
                print "Canceled/closed operation"
            ############################
        else:
            cmds.warning("Please select an item in ANMG field")


    def slotCancel(self):
        self.close()


class PublishInfoUI(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, asset, parent = None, modal = False):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, modal = modal)

        self.ui = publishInfoUI_test.Ui_PublishInfo()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.assets = asset

        self.fill_details()

    def fill_details(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit_rigUsed.setText(self.assets.text(0))
        self.ui.lineEdit_anmLocation.setText(self.assets.text(5))
        self.ui.textEdit_comment.setText(self.assets.text(7))

    def getValues(self):
        #Solution 1:
        #Do the modification here
        self.assets.setText(6, self.ui.lineEdit_description.text() )
        self.assets.setText(7, self.ui.textEdit_comment.toPlainText() )
        self.assets.setText(8, self.ui.textEdit_Vcomment.toPlainText() )
        #End solution 1

        #Solution2:
        #Return a new asset and do the modification in MigrationUi class
        assetToReturn = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
        assetToReturn.setText(6, self.ui.lineEdit_description.text() ) #Feel free to add more infos if necessary
        assetToReturn.setText(7, self.ui.textEdit_comment.toPlainText() )
        assetToReturn.setText(8, self.ui.textEdit_Vcomment.toPlainText() )
        return assetToReturn
        #End solution 2
```

Comment: I tried out both solutions and it works! Was wondering if you could tell me why is Solution 2 not preferred? Eg. Harder to maintain/ debug etc?

Comment: Sorry, one more question - In my mainUI, the `publish` button that I had requires values to be grab from both the QTreeWidget in the Migrate Anmg as well as the subUI, is it possible to do so? For example, I will need the `Type` in subUI in which mainUI has no columns for it

Comment: In French, we have an expression that says "This is a matter of taste and colours", this applies here. I prefer the way solution 1 do the job. What the migrate UI could say is: "If you want to update the QTreeWidget, do it completely, don't return me a QTreeWidgetItem finish the job for you."
Solution 2 is about twice the code of solution 1, even if it is just a small amount of code it can leads to more error. Yeah... as I said, a matter of taste and colour, just use the one that you feel the more comfortable with.

Comment: I guess, if you only have one value in subUI you want to keep, you could add an other column to your `QTreeWidget` and hide it using [hideColumn](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreeview.html#hideColumn). Fill it's value at the same place as for the other attributes.